# Constructing a Borel Measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable. Let $\nu(E) = \int_Ef\,d\mu$. Show that $\nu$ is a Borel measure.

Showing this is a measure is easy enough - just check what happens to nulls sets and disjoint unions. How do I know it's a Borel measure - is it because $f$ is not defined otherwise? (The problem statement doesn't say what $\mu$ is - I assume Lebesgue measure)

Comment: It is enough to check that $\nu$ is defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is sort of obvious given that $\int_E f \, d\mu$ is defined for any Borel set $E$ (as long as $f$ is non-negative Borel measurable and $\mu$ is a Borel measure).

Comment: It is unclear to me what's supposed to happen if you have some sets $E$ such that $\int_E f^+\,d\mu=\infty$ and $\int_E f^-\,d\mu=\infty$ (say, $f=\sin$ and $E=[0,\infty)$).

Comment: I failed to mention $f$ is positive, sorry